# Spring security does not intercept URLs In Tomcat configured with IIS ISAPI

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I am new into Spring security and trying to integrate it with an existing application. This legacy application deployed in a tomcat 7 server behind IIS. ISAPI filter is used to dispatch request to this tomcat instance.

Since my early attempts to integrate spring security to this legacy application was not a success, I copied sample a working spring security application (tested) to the tomcat instance and completely removed the legacy application. To my surprise it still fails to intercept secure urls. (but this sample application is working fine when I am running with maven tomcat plugin.), So I am wondering why my application is not working in the tomcat instance configured with ISAPI and IIS.

I have added forward url patterns to url worker map and I can successfully hit the secured controllers with out authenticating first.

Please find my tomcat log

```
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [C:\Server_APP_Location\XYZ_APP\Tomcat\7.0.30\shared\classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'minProcessors' to '5' did not find a matching property.
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'maxProcessors' to '300' did not find a matching property.
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Engine/Logger'.
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlValidation' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlNamespaceAware' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Engine/Host/Logger'.
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context/Logger'.
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 575 ms
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.30
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:15 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [158] milliseconds.
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
SEVERE: Error starting static Resources

Jul 06, 2016 11:32:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error in resourceStart()
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal

Jul 06, 2016 11:32:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Server_APP_Location\XYZ_APP\Tomcat\7.0.30\webapps\someWebApplication
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 06, 2016 11:32:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    INFO  ContextLoader:273 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed     Jul 06 23:32:16 AEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy

    INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/C:/Server_APP_Location/XYZ_APP/Tomcat/7.0.30/webapps/someWebApplication/WEB-INF/classes/application-context.xml]
DEBUG DefaultDocumentLoader:72 - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
DEBUG PluggableSchemaResolver:140 - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
DEBUG PluggableSchemaResolver:118 - Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.2.xsd

 DEBUG BeanUtils:443 - No property editor [org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptorEditor] found for type org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequestInterceptor according to 'Editor' suffix convention
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:1531 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0'
 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:105 - Looking for request mappings in application context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed     Jul 06 23:32:16 AEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
     INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:185 - Mapped "{[/api/json/{id}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public rest.demo.JsonRestObject rest.demo.RestController.getJsonRestObject(java.lang.Integer)
     INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:185 - Mapped "{[/apiv2/json/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public rest.demo.JsonRestObject rest.demo.RestController2.getJsonResponse(java.lang.Integer)
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0'

 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.web.context.NullSecurityContextRepository#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.NullRequestCache#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'authenticationEntryPoint': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'customRestFilter': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'restAuthenticationProvider': no URL paths identified
 DEBUG BNUHM:86 - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor': no URL paths identified

 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'

 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0'

 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.context.NullSecurityContextRepository#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.context.NullSecurityContextRepository#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.context.NullSecurityContextRepository#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.context.NullSecurityContextRepository#0'
 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:112 - Initializing new StandardServletEnvironment

 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'customRestFilter'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'customRestFilter'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'restAuthenticationProvider'

 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:1531 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'

 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:116 - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:1531 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#19'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
 DEBUG DLBF:1531 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name '(inner bean)#19'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#19'
 DEBUG DLBF:1531 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'authenticationEntryPoint'

 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.NullRequestCache#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.NullRequestCache#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.NullRequestCache#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.NullRequestCache#0'

 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#21'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#22'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#22'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#23'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#23'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:1531 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0'

 DEBUG DLBF:1531 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:159 - Validated configuration attributes
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'

     INFO  DefaultSecurityFilterChain:28 - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3ba71e33, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@58afc4dd, rest.demo.CustomRestSecurityFilter@7ba5b6a7, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3c7acd5c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@22407209, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@34febe70, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4088c63e]
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:1531 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'

 DEBUG StandardEnvironment:116 - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
 DEBUG BeanUtils:443 - No property editor [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChainEditor] found for type org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain according to 'Editor' suffix convention
 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:116 - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#26'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean '(inner bean)#26'
 DEBUG DLBF:1531 - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.context.NullSecurityContextRepository#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.NullRequestCache#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:215 - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory'
 DEBUG DLBF:435 - Creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory'
 DEBUG DLBF:509 - Eagerly caching bean 'org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory' to allow for resolving potential circular references
 DEBUG DLBF:463 - Finished creating instance of bean 'org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'authenticationEntryPoint'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'customRestFilter'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'restAuthenticationProvider'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor'
 DEBUG XmlWebApplicationContext:858 - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@3b6ecdb3]

 DEBUG ContextLoader:308 - Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
 INFO  ContextLoader:313 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2371 ms
 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:116 - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
 DEBUG DelegatingFilterProxy:172 - Initializing filter 'springSecurityFilterChain'
 DEBUG DLBF:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'
```

When I am hitting the restful controller I can see following log,

```
DEBUG DispatcherServlet:823 - DispatcherServlet with name 'RestFulServlet' processing GET request for [/retail/online/api/json/1]
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:226 - Looking up handler method for path /api/json/1
DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:233 - Returning handler method [public rest.demo.JsonRestObject rest.demo.RestController.getJsonRestObject(java.lang.Integer)]
DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:246 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'restController'
DEBUG DispatcherServlet:912 - Last-Modified value for [/retail/online/api/json/1] is: -1
DEBUG RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor:150 - Written [rest.demo.JsonRestObject@1493b4f0] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter@6d4c031d]
DEBUG DispatcherServlet:999 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'RestFulServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG DispatcherServlet:966 - Successfully completed request
```

Web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestFulServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestFulServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/online/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Application context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="rest.demo" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<security:http create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:custom-filter ref="customRestFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Username: jack Password: jill" />
</bean>
<bean id="customRestFilter" class="rest.demo.CustomRestSecurityFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="restAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>
<bean id="restAuthenticationProvider" class="rest.demo.RestAuthenticationProvider" />
```

I am running spring security and framework version 3.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this issue was due to the fact that the requests coming to the tomcat getting forwarded by another web application to the application that I am trying to implement spring security, as follows

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher(uri);
dispatcher.forward(req, rsp);
```

So all I had to do is add dispatcher flags to spring security filter

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

So If you are facing a similar issue make sure how the request is dispatched to your application.